# 52 week Momentum strategy from basics with tanmay and prateek youtube course

Tags: stocks, technical-analysis

If anyone has watch the youtube online course basics of trading with tanmay and prateek, please help with following.

The logic behind selecting the stocks? As far as I understand is: "We have to observe weekly chart of nifty 100 stocks and select the stocks which stock has weekly close above 52 week high at friday 3:00pm."

Is it true?
What is the best screener for this strategy?

Comment: If you don't understand it, don't do it. You'll lose all your money.

Comment: Capitalization-weighted index funds are momentum funds that give the most support to the largest companies. Also, they systematically re-balance. Actually, I would rather have a portfolio of particular-prospects.

Comment: Beware of data mining bias. The trading strategy is likely to be worthless if it was the result of repeatedly using the same data to search for profitable trading rules. The pitfall is similar to p-hacking (in statistical parlance) and overfitting (in statistical and machine learning parlance).

Answer (score 1):

Last year someone did an analysis of stock performance and observed that US stocks where "V" is the second letter of the ticker symbol averaged an 89% gain whereas the S&P 500 gained 16%.

A stellar perform in the early years was the Super Bowl Indicator which was 92% accurate in its first 50 years.

Such performance is due to randomness.  IOW, the performance is coincidental.

I surmise that the observation of "tanmay and prateek" are just more of the same.